# Lookup of locale EJB in a POJO class throws NameNotFoundException

Tags: database, jsf, javabeans, jndi

I try to lookup a `@Stateless` bean inside a POJO which is in the same package where the bean is. The bean is not null when I use it in my `@ManagedBean` controller class and I can do CRUD operations.
Here is the code for lookup in ArticlesBundle.java:

```
public class ArticlesBundle extends ResourceBundle{                 
protected static final String BASE_NAME = "ArticlesLcl.findForLocale";
private Map<String,String> messages = new HashMap<>();            
private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
protected final Control DB_CONTROL = new DBControl();       

public ArticlesBundle(){        
    setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BASE_NAME, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale(), DB_CONTROL));
}        

protected ArticlesBundle(Locale locale){        
    setParent(ResourceBundle.getBundle(BASE_NAME, locale, DB_CONTROL));        
}  

public ArticlesBundle(Map<String,String> messages){
    this.messages = messages;
}        

@Override
protected Object handleGetObject(String key){        
    return messages != null ? messages.get(key) : parent.getObject(key);
}

@Override
public Enumeration<String> getKeys(){        
    return parent.getKeys();
}

protected class DBControl extends Control{
    @Override
    public ResourceBundle newBundle
            (String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, IOException
    {                             
        String language = locale.getLanguage();
        Map<String,String> messages = getArticless(locale); 

        System.out.println("getArticles("+language+") = "+getArticles(locale));
        return new ArticlesBundle(messages);
    }         
    public Map<String,String> getArticles(Locale locale){            
        String language = locale.getLanguage();
        try {            
            Context ctx = new InitialContext();            
            ArticlesLclFacade arBean = (ArticlesLclFacade) ctx.lookup("java:gesht/ArticlesLclFacade");
            List<ArticlesLcl> articles = arBean.getArticles(language);
            for(Iterator<ArticlesLcl> it = articles.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
                ArticlesLcl article = it.next();
                messages.put(article.getArId().getArId().toString(), article.getArTitle());                
            }                                          

        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 

        return messages;
    }        
}        
}
```

In ArticlesFacade:

```
@Stateless
public class ArticlesFacade extends AbstractFacade<ArticlesLcl> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "gtestPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public ArticlesFacade() {
    super(ArticlesLcl.class);
}
public List<ArticlesLcl> getArticless(String language){
    Query q = em.createNamedQuery("ArticlesLcl.findForLocale", ArticlesLcl.class);
    q.setParameter("lang", language);
    return q.getResultList();
}
}
```

Faces-Config.xml

```
<resource-bundle>
        <base-name>com.gesht.bundles.ArticlesBundle</base-name>
        <var>article</var>
    </resource-bundle>
```

It throws the following exception:

```
SEVERE: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:gtest/ArticlesLclFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:gtest/ArticlesLclFacade]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)      
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1436)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1400)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1296)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:841)
    at com.gtest.bundles.test.<init>(test.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2571)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1436)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1400)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1354)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1296)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1028)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationResourceBundle.getResourceBundle(ApplicationResourceBundle.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.getResourceBundle(ApplicationAssociate.java:608)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.getResourceBundle(ApplicationImpl.java:700)
    at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.getResourceBundle(ApplicationWrapper.java:526)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesResourceBundleELResolver.getValue(FacesResourceBundleELResolver.java:83)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:179)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:92)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:61)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:45)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:45)
    at org.primefaces.component.datagrid.DataGridRenderer.encodeTable(DataGridRenderer.java:156)
    at org.primefaces.component.datagrid.DataGridRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataGridRenderer.java:91)
    at org.primefaces.component.datagrid.DataGridRenderer.encodeEnd(DataGridRenderer.java:53)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.renderView(RewriteViewHandler.java:186)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:gtest/ArticlesLclFacade
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:772)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:744)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:177)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:498)
    ... 108 more
```

I use Glassfish Server 3+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used syntax `ArticlesLclFacade arBean = (ArticlesLclFacade) ctx.lookup("java:global/gtest/ArticlesLclFacade");` and there is no more `NamingException` thrown.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Stateless(mappedName="articlesLclFacade")
public class ArticlesLclFacade extends AbstractFacade {
```

then in your try clause

```
ArticlesLclFacade arBean = (ArticlesLclFacade)ctx.lookup("articlesLclFacadee");
```

Or I can guess you can also use the EJB annotation as this :

```
@EJB
private ArticlesLclFacade arBean;
```

Comment: I have defined my session bean exactly like this and in my managed bean I have injected it with that EJB annotation this way. But inside that POJO I have to lookup my bean using JNDI and for some reason which I don't know it's always null. Possibilities as far as I can assume are my POJO method is called before bean is injected or they live in two different threads. For the first one I tried a `@PostConstruct` initilaization method which didn't work, for the second I don't know what to do.

Comment: Sorry in my answer it should be `ArticlesLclFacade arBean = (ArticlesLclFacade)ctx.lookup("articlesLclFacade");` instead of `ArticlesLclFacade arBean = (ArticlesLclFacade)ctx.lookup("articlesLclFacadee");`
 
Can you post all of the code involved in that part of your program? I really want to help you to solve this.

Comment: Thank you @Sujan , after I created a POJO whithout a main method, now I get `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:gtest/ArticleLclFacade` and not a `Got null ComponentInvocation`

Comment: You have this problem because the context lookup cannot find the bean. `java:gtest/ArticleLclFacade` is not right. Please edit your question and put all of the code involved. Why don't you name the bean with `(mappedName="articlesLclFacade")` and then use the name in the look up, as in my example ?

Comment: I updated my question and added more code with my new exception. I'll try the `meppedName` right now.

Comment: Ok , in ArticleFacade write `@Stateless(mappedName="articlesLclFacade")`, then in the other bean just declare 
`@EJB
private ArticlesLclFacade arBean;` as a field. After that , arBean will be accessible anywhere in the bean, and you won't need to use context lookup to access it. What's the scope of your 'POJO' ? Request ? View ? Session ? Application ? Custom ?

Comment: It's the same @Sujan. I get the same exception. This code is for a bundle class which is supposed to get messages from DB. I didn't include the rest of the class for simplicity. because this part is the cause of the problem. I you find it helpful I'll include the entire code of test bundle.

Comment: It's not a managed bean. It's only a java class. In my managed bean which is `ArticlesController` I use `@Ejb private ArticlesFacade arBean;` but in that POJO I need to use context lookup to access it I suppose.

Comment: Did you check your persistence.xml and glassfish-ressources.xml file ? Did you declare the JDBC connection pool and JDBC-resource correctly?

Comment: Yes I did. I can do CRUD operation with no problem.

Comment: OK that's great, now can you tell me how and where do you instantiate the test class?

Comment: I use it in the view as `<h:outputText value="#{test.title}"/>` and for that I have added the bundle in faces-config.xml, and I have used those `println(arBean)` line to test it. When I want to access the view page I get the exception.

Comment: Can I see what you've in `faces-config.xml` ? You need at least a request scoped bean for this to work. 1. Add EJB annotation as in my example in your Test class. 2. Remove your try and catch blocks and replace by just `System.out.println(arBean);`  it should work.  Are you trying to feed your resource bundle with data from database ? If yes, then you need to use special classes for that purpose such as DBControl, DBResourceBundle, etc, it's a whole different story.

Comment: It is a bundle and if I annotate it with `@ManagedBean` it throws a `MissingResourceException`.

Comment: Post what you have in faces-config. xml. Put that in faces-config.xml and try again <managed-bean>
   <managed-bean-name>test</managed-bean-name>
   <managed-bean-class>gtest.Test</managed-bean-class>
   <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
     </managed-bean>

The class's path might be wrong, modify it accordingly.

Comment: I just saw your faces-config.xml. You declared that class as a resource bundle, that was the mistake. Resource bundles are usually text properties files. However, you can also extend ResourceBundle to a class that return translations (i8n). It can be achieved easily, [please have a look here](http://blog.eisele.net/2012/08/resource-bundle-tricks-and-best.html)

Comment: I already read that article Sujan. I've put my bundle class that extends DBControl in the question as well. I've seen Markus's code, It uses EntityManagerFactory to retrieve data from db in his resource bundle class but it throws `Got null ComponentInvocation` exception and therefore I decided to use JNDI lookup to retrieve messages from db.